# How to initialize Map from array of key value pairs

Tags: typescript

I have an array like:

```
const myArray = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
```

I want to create Map from myArray (In TypeScript, works fine in JS).

This does not work:

```
const myMap = new Map(myArray);
```

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
...
```

But, this works:

```
const myMap = new Map([['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typescript automatically infers the type of `myArray` as:

```
string[][]
```

But the Map constructor *only* accepts iterables which contain arrays of *exactly two items*.

You can define the `myArray` as `const` so that TS doesn't automatically widen the type from "an array of arrays of 2 strings" to "an array of arrays of strings":

```
const myArray = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']] as const;
```

Another way, for older versions of TS that don't support `as const` (which was introduced in 3.4):

```
const myArray: Array<[string, string]> = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
```

Or, if you need to preserve the keys/values exactly:

```
const myArray = [['key1', 'value1'] as ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'] as ['key2', 'value2']];
```